# After block auto feet for mobile version of browser

Tags: css

I use wordpress and as a customized solution I used the following code in the menu bar in order to have next to logo an additional text:

```
.navbar-header:after{
    content: 'My title test';
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Everything seem all right in a computer browser.However in mobile browser the text doesn't seem to fixed into the mobile option and stays fixed when scrolling down to page.

How is it possible to fix it?

Comment: If you are using **wordpress** why go to this solution ?  it offer **slogan** you can put your text there !!

Comment: @KrDjamel using slogan is it possible to have both the logo and a text (some of text I would like to be a hyperlink)?

Comment: **Logo** by default  should be inside an  **hyperlink** a **link** to the home page so  it can be an **image** or **text** !!  **slogan** usually has the attributes of being memorable !! now  if  you want the logo has an **image & text** then make Logo image using (photoshop or illustrator) that contain **image and text** !!  this is a the proper way !! i hope this was helpful !!